# Setup pgpool issue

Tags: postgresql, pgpool

Trying to setup pgpool 4.4.2, but when tried to config the authentication to use scram-sha-256 it give me the following error:

```
$ bin/pg_enc -m -k /export/home/postgres/.pgpoolkey -u pgpool -p

db password:

trying to read key from file /export/home/postgres/.pgpoolkey
ERROR: pid 3018597: AES encryption is not supported by this build
```

Already tried to install from source using `--with-openssl` but without luck.
Any ideas what is cause of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This error states that your build doesn't contain AES Encryption
Please make sure you are building Pgpool-II with OpenSSL support enabled. Use the `--with-openssl` option during the configuration step when building Pgpool-II from source.